# How to share a window context between source files in GLFW 3

Tags: c++, glfw

Ok, I've been trying to share a window context between different source files, mainly my main c++ file and the main gameloop, it looks like this(stripped down), it's made in OpenGL 3.3 and GLFW 3 using Code::Blocks 13.12. I'm trying to do this to cut down on size of my individual files

Everytime I'm trying to compile I'm getting:

```
mutiple definitions of 'window'
```

inside the mainLoop.cpp file.

WINDOW.h

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

//include glfw etc...

GLFWwindow* window;

#endif //WINDOW.h
```

mainLoop.cpp

```
//include glfw etc...

#include "WINDOW.h"

void mainLoop()
{
    do{
        //some code that uses 'window' context
    }while( glfwGetKey( window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) == 0 ); //<- "window" causing problems
}
//relevant cleanup
```

main.cpp

```
//include necessary headers (glfw, glu, glew, and others)

#include "WINDOW.h"

void mainLoop();

int main( void )
{
    //initialize opengl and whatnot.
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 512, 288, "NULL", NULL, NULL );
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    mainLoop();

}
```

I'm not sure why I can't use a context this way, it works if my "mainLoop" code is by itself inside main (using the WINDOW.hpp).
Help much appreciated.

Comment: It has nothing to with GLFW. You are now including `window.h` in two source files, so the variable `window` is defined twice. If you really want a global variable, you can look at the related question : [How can I use extern to share globe variables between source files in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106468/how-can-i-use-extern-to-share-globe-variables-between-source-files-in-c)

Comment: @Leiaz using extern on "GLFWwindow* window" just gives me undefined references to 'window' everywhere for some reason.

Comment: That's because with `extern` the variable is just declared,  it still needs to actually be defined somewhere (in a cpp file), but just once.

Comment: Why don't you pass it as a parameter to `mainLoop`?

Comment: @Leiaz I thought window = glfwCreateWindow() was the definition?

Comment: No, that is just an assignment. Previously you had it defined in your header, which made it defined in all the cpp files including that header. That definition should be moved to one cpp file, and the header with extern just declare in your other cpp files that the variable exists somewhere. But @molbdnilo is right that you could pass it as a parameter and avoid having a global variable.

Comment: thanks both Leiaz and molbdnilo, passing 'window' as a parameter worked perfectly, now I just have to figure out everything else that got broken when I moved the main loop :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was much easier than what I initially thought. I didn't have to use `GLFWwindow* window` as a global variable, I just needed to pass `window` as a parameter like:`void mainLoop( GLFWwindow* window );`
Now the window spawns as it should!

Thanks both @Leiaz and @molbdnilo for helping me, it was much appreciated!